# How to get Firebase Database data tree in array?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Firebase structures its data as JSON. Unlike SQL, there are no tables.

Is there an easy way to convert the JSON into an array?

Comment: Are you planning to use Firebase in Android?

Comment: No, I am using JavaScript. The method I am doing to show user-friendly data requires an array. Though, if no can do, then I will modify it to accept JSON trees @JuanPablo